# What is the purpose of being able to name tuple values when returning them from methods in C#?

Tags: c#, tuples

Consider the following code:

```cs
static (int, string) GetValues()
{
    return (123, "abc");
}

static (int number, string text) GetValues()
{
    return (123, "abc");
}
```

What is the point of being able to name the tuple values "number" and "text" in the method signature?

Comment: @Izzy but the caller can rename them anyway, so it didn't make much sense?

Comment: To indicate what each value *means*, isn't it? That's kind of the whole point of having *names*, isn't it? Try referring to all your variables/parameters/methods/classes with just a number instead.

Comment: They caller can rename them, *but the caller can also **not** do that...*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Naming your tuples means you can do this:

```
static (int number, string text) GetValues()
{
    return (123, "abc");
}

var result = GetValues();

Console.WriteLine($"{result.number}, {result.text}");
```

If you don't name the tuple members in the method signature, you have to refer to them as `result.Item1` and `result.Item2`.

Comment: Or you can name them in the calling code, of course. But you have to specify the names there, which is less convenient.

Comment: Yep, of course.

Comment: Not only less convenient but also wrong. The calling code does not know and is not responsible for explaining the meaning of the returned values.

Comment: In fairness, meanings can change. If a method returns `(string name, int age)` is it really so bad to do `var (studentName, studentAge) = ...`?

Comment: @canton7: maybe i've misunderstood, but i thought Jon has suggested to rename the `Item1`, `Item2` to something meaningful.Like: `var x = GetValues(); int number = x.Item1; ...`. But that could break(if the impl. of the method changes) and is also not the reponsibility of the calling code.

Answer (score 4):

In the first case, items inside tuple do not have names:

```
static (int, string) GetValues()
{
    return (123, "abc");
}

var r = GetValues().item1;
```

In the second case, you can get the values by name:

```
static (int number, string text) GetValues()
{
    return (123, "abc");
}
var r = GetValues().number;
```

Answer (score 4):

It allows the caller to refer to the tuple elements by name very simply. For example:

```cs
static (int, string) GetValuesWithoutNames() =>
    (123, "abc");

static (int number, string text) GetValuesWithNames() =>
    (123, "abc");

// Urgh: without specifying a name at the call site, we only get
// Item1 and Item2.
var noNames = GetValuesWithoutNames();
Console.WriteLine(noNames.Item1);

// Also somewhat urgh: we can specify a name at the call site, and
// then use it, but it's more verbose and can lead to inconsistency.
(int number, string text) withCallerNames = GetValuesWithoutNames();
Console.WriteLine(withCallerNames.number);

// Yay: if the method declares the names, callers can just use them directly.
var withNames = GetValuesWithNames();
Console.WriteLine(withNames.number);
```

Note how in the last version the names are *only* declared in the method... so you don't end up with potential inconsistency between multiple callers, unless they *choose* to redeclare with a different name.

Answer (score 3):

At runtime...the names "almost" disappear.
For methods and properties...the compiler adds an attribute called `TupleElementNamesAttribute` to the return type.
This helps making things work with different assemblies (where there is no source).

Comment: I hadn't considered the cross assembly impact, so that's good to know. +1